# Preview images from several recourring select/preview areas

Tags: jquery, image, select

In a page I have the following code repeating several times:

```
<tr>

    <td>

        <div class="image_showcase"></div> <!-- This is the images preview area -->

    </td>

</tr>

<tr data-name="select_name">

    <td>

        <select> <!-- This is the select that allows to pick images -->
            <option name='img_01' value='img_01'>Image 01</option>
            <option name='img_02' value='img_02'>Image 02</option>
            <option name='img_03' value='img_03'>Image 03</option>
        </select>       

    </td>

</td>
```

The select prompts you to choose between several images/backgrounds while the above "" should give the user a preview. 
I've hence came down with the following script:

```
jQuery("tr[data-name='select_name'] select").change(function(){

    jQuery("div.image_showcase").css('background-image', 'url("http://127.0.0.1/name/img/'+jQuery(this).val()+'.jpg")');

});
```

The script works, and gives you a preview of the images, but has 2 severe flaws I cannot seem to overcome:

1. If I reload the page, the preview area will result empty. I infact need to interact with the select first in order for the image to show. I realize I have to target the "tr[data-name='select_name'] select option:selected" somehow, but I didn't really manage.
2. As previously stated, these "Select+Preview area" occour more than once in the page. As the code stands, if I edit one select (out of 4, let's say), every preview area will change image. How can I change my code so that every selects targets the preview area right above it?